# Array outcome from foreach loop from SQL Query

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Looking for the code below to create an array of 1's and 0's from this query. At the moment, the result from $rows is:

```
Array ( [discontinued] => 1, ) Array ( [discontinued] => 1 ) Array ( [discontinued] => 0 ) Array ( [discontinued] => 0 ) Array ( [discontinued] => 1 )....
```

where I would rather have something like:

```
Array [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 1....
```

Anyone could help me out on this, it would be greatly appreciated. **Please don't comment about vulnerabilities in the code; I know it's already there. I am just a beginner...I just want the core guts of it to work.**

Cheers! :)

```
function checkDiscontinued($dbh, $idDiscontinuedArray) {
try {
    foreach ($idDiscontinuedArray as $id) {

        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT discontinued FROM `$id` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
        $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        print_r($rows);

        }
        if ($rows['discontinued'] == TRUE) { 
            //echo $id . "Action if true";
        } else {
            changeDiscontinued($dbh, $id, $idDiscontinuedArray);
            //echo $id . "Items already discontinued!";
            }       
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to have the values in `$rows`, the result of `$pdo->fetch()`, to be numerically indexed, you can set the fetch style in the parameters to [`PDO::FETCH_NUM`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

However, if you're looking for a "full array" of all records, you can switch to [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead of pulling in a single result as with `fetch()`:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could modify my code to get something like Array  [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 1